# Pipelines in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, pipeline, polynomials

I'm learning Data Analysis with Python and there is something I can not figure out.
I understand that exists three options to develop a model: Linear, Linear Multiple, and Polynomial. However, then I get into a new concept called 'pipelines'. I put some code here:

```
Input=[('scale',StandardScaler()), ('polynomial', PolynomialFeatures(include_bias=False)), ('model',LinearRegression())]
```

Normalization's ok, however, I do not understand why I introduce as a parameter a PolynomialFeature if I will use a Linear Model??? It does not make sense to me. Please, could someone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misconception. Linear Model refers to the *parameters, not the features*. Say you have features `x` and Values `y`. You linear model will be

```
y = a_0 + a_1 * x
```

You can generate additional features by arithmetic operations like e.g. `x**2`. Now your model becomes

```
y = a_0 + a_1 * x + a_2 * x**2
```

It is still a *linear* model, because `a_0`, `a_1` and `a_2` are linear. It just has a polynomial feature.

Comment: Now that makes sense to me!